# jQuery $.post processing JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly read my JSON response from a jQuery $.post() request.

In the below jQuery code, I populate an associative array of strings from elements from the DOM based on the corresponding "color_entry_id" which I use as the key:

```
var image_links = {};
$(this).find('input[name="color_id"]').each(function() {
    var color_entry_id = $(this).val();
    var image_link = $(this).parent().find('input[name="edit_image"].' + color_entry_id).val();
    image_links[color_entry_id] = image_link;
});
```

Then I make the POST request, sending my array of "image_links":

```
$.post(
    "test.php",
    { id: product_id, "images[]": jQuery.makeArray(image_links) },
    function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(response.images, function(index, item) {
             alert(item);
        });
    }
);
```

Also, as shown above, I try to loop through the response array and output each item, which I want to be a string, but I only get "[object Object]" as the alerted value. I don't know how to make it display the strings I'm trying to display!

Here is the PHP code for test.php:

```
<?php
    $product_id = $_POST['id'];
    $images = $_POST['images'];

    $response = array();
    $response['id'] = $product_id;
    $response['images'] = $images;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And here's what the relevant part of the DOM looks like:

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{ color_entry_id }}' name='color_id' />
<p><img src='{{ color_img_link }}' /></p>
<p>Image Link: <input class='{{ color_entry_id }}' name='edit_image' type='text' size='150' value='{{ color_img_link }}' /></p>
<div class='colors {{ color_entry_id }}'>
    <div class='img_color'>
        <a href='javascript:void' style='background:...' class='selected'></a>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering whether perhaps I'm doing the JSON encoding incorrectly on the PHP side or if I'm just looping through the response incorrectly in the jQuery. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: What are you expecting `makeArray` to do to your `image_links` object? And you'll have better luck with `console.log` for debugging, `alert` makes a mess of things when it stringifies them.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I had used previously for a different application that worked fine. Should I not be using that?

Comment: But why are you using `makeArray`? What do you expect `$.makeArray({a: 'b', c: 'd'})` to do? What is the server expecting to find in `$_POST['images']`?

Comment: You're right, I actually am passing another value that is something like "1": {blue, green, red} which I am using $.makeArray() for. But I shouldn't be using it for images. When I get rid of the makeArray, it returns {"1": "image_link"}, but I still don't know how I can grab "image_link" from that. When I try response.images.1, it doesn't work.

Comment: when you run $(this).find('input[name=color_id]') in a console..do you return anything?  When i try something like that..it doesn't pick up the input elements.

Comment: Yeah, that part works. I do get color_entry_id values.

Comment: here's a hint.  The data object you're getting back from the post is: {"id":"abc","images":[{"color123":"somelink.com\/123","color223":"somelink.com\/223"}]}; this reads as data.images is an array w/ 1 element--an object w/ 2 colorxyz properties.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok then..the data object you're getting back from the post is: `{"id":"abc","images":[{"color123":"somelink.com\/123","color223":"somelink.com\/‌​223"}]};`

If you change your alert, you'll find the values you're looking for:

```
$.post(
    "test.php",
    { id: product_id, "images[]": jQuery.makeArray(image_links) },
    function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        var images = response.images[0];
        for (var i in images){
            alert(images[i]);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I added json_encode($images) to my php which was why it was messing up.

Answer (score 32):

$.post expects xml by default, you need to specify the response format

```
$.post(
    "test.php",
    { id: product_id, images : jQuery.makeArray(image_links) },
    function(response) {
        // Response is automatically a json object
        for(var i = 0; i < response.images.length; i++) {
            alert(response.images[i]);
        }
    }, 'json' // <-- HERE
);
```

Also, consider adding a content type header in your php script

```
    <?php
    header("Content-type: application/json"); // Adding a content type helps as well
    $product_id = $_POST['id'];
    $images = $_POST['images'];

    $response = array();
    $response['id'] = $product_id;
    $response['images'] = $images;

    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! But it still doesn't help with grabbing the info I need. Any suggestions for that aspect?

Comment: I've updated the javascript portion of the answer, try that :) You didn't need to do "images[]", as posting a javascript array will automagically do that for you

Comment: That just steps through each letter of the response string one at a time. It doesn't grab the full string and I have no idea why

Comment: Do you have inspect element in your browser, or google chrome? You'll be able to inspect the network request, and check the variables being sent out. If you have exactly what I have posted, it should work. My best guess at this point, is to check what's being sent via AJAX, and confirm it's truly an array

Comment: xml isn't the default expected data type, "intelligent guess" (auto) is the default, which should have little trouble identifying JSON.

Comment: At the very least, it doesn't hurt to be explicit

Comment: What if would like to use a deferred function instead of an anonymous for callback ? like $.post(url, {}, 'json').done(function(json){ //do something; });
that would work ? (actually is not working for me :(   )

Answer (score 3):

A pretty basic example would be something like :

```
$.post('test.php', {"id": 42}, function (json) {
 console.log(json);
}, 'json');
```

PHP example

```
$number = rand(1,$_POST["id"]);
return print json_encode($number);
```