# jQuery Ajax response fails with invalid characters

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firebug

Im calling an ajax function and getting back some JSON data.

Ive looked at the data and it all looks like the server is responded as it should

However FireBug reports an issue and my program fails.

**This is JSON the response**

```
{"status":"success","message":"item was added to cart OK","cost":38.5,"qty":11}
```

**This is the error from firebug**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character


return window.JSON.parse( data );
```

Here is a screenshot of the callstack;[image]

**Here is the Javascript**

```
$('.submitform').click( function() {
$.post( 'myrll.com/cart/add', $('[name=myform]').serialize(), function(data) {
    var new_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    if(new_data.status=='error')
    {
        alert(new_data.message);
    }
    else
    {
        add_item_to_cart(new_data.cost,new_data.qty);
    }
},
'json' // I expect a JSON response
);
```

});

**And finally my php server script**

```
    $sys_message['status'] = 'success'
    $sys_message['qty'] = $total_items; //this is INT
    $sys_message['cost'] = $this->sfcart->total_cost_contents(); //FLOAT
    $sys_message['message'] = $message; //string

    echo json_encode($sys_message);return;
```

Comment: I had this similar problem..
 encode the json value which is returnin from server and decode it on client side...

Comment: I did, I will post my javascript code in 1 min

Comment: Can we see your code that does the actual AJAX call? It seems like your AJAX response is stored as a string literal, rather than a JavaScript object.

Comment: that because you are trying to parse json instead of json string

Comment: You should not need to do explicitly parse the JSON using .parseJSON(). If your web server returns a JSON object and you have specified you are expecting a JSON response, then jQuery is smart enough to figure that out on its own. Try removing that line and working with data instead of new_data and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

you are assigning string to the response param not json object. thaty it give you an error. assign direct object to the response param instead of string

**You current Response (string coz there is a "" around this)**

```
response = "{"status":"success","message":"item was added to cart OK","cost":38.5,"qty":11}"
```

**You need Response (object no quotation)**

```
response = {"status":"success","message":"item was added to cart OK","cost":38.5,"qty":11}
```

with out Quotation ("). and then try it works

Comment: Ill add my php because Im not sure what or how that happend

Comment: try to add "header("Content-type: application/json"); " above you php code like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475652/jquery-post-processing-json-response#answer-10475737

Comment: I removed this line and it worked: ,'json' // I expect a JSON response

Comment: Maybe this is bcoz you data is not returning in json format from php side. if you put ,'json'// back and try to add "header("Content-type: application/json");" in your php side code above json encode. may be it will also works

Answer (score 0):

1) It fails at `response = conv( response );` - string probably?

2) Make sure the `Content-type` is set to `application/json`.

Comment: @Thomas I think it does. It's just that Pinal does not know how to format answers better.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line and it worked: Im not sure why, possible conflict with parse ?
If anyone can explain  this than that will be helpful to myself and others

```
 ,'json' // I expect a JSON response
```