# how to pass variables from php to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why i can't pass the variable co2 to jquery function? nothing shows up
where's wrong ? i want to use co2 variable in my jquery function.

```
  <?php
  ... 
$co2 = (($miles / 41.986) * 20.88 * 2.7) / 2204.6; 
echo json_encode(array('co2' => $co2));
   ?>
```

jquery:

```
   $("#aircalc").click(function(){
        var dept = $("#dept").val();
        var dest = $("#dest").val();
        $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest: dest}, function(data){
        var a = data.co2;
        $("#airanswer").html(a);

                });

        });
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475652/jquery-post-processing-json-response you can do: `var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data); var a = response.co2`

Comment: see in  your browser  what you have got from ajax respone

Comment: I edited my Code I posted in Answer as per your Condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not access `co2` because you are calling regular post ajax and return `json` object you need to call ajax request with json type something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json"
  url: 'airtravel.php',
  data: {dept: dept, dest: dest}
})
  .done(function( data ) {
        var a = data.co2;
        $("#airanswer").html(a);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 $("#aircalc").click(function(){
        var dept = $("#dept").val();
        var dest = $("#dest").val();
        values: [ <?php echo $co2; ?>],
        $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest: dest}, function(data){
                var a = data.values[0];


                $("#airanswer").html(a);

            });


    });
```