# Access obj property from JSON using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a simple object from `data` as you can see for example JSON bellow. But when I try to access it like `data.Title` it returns undefined. What's wrong here?

Jquery:

```
$.post('/Example/GetData', { Id: _Id }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.Title);//this returns undefined
                console.log(data);
            });
```

console.log() shows like this:

```
{"ProductId":22,"Title":"my wallet","Des":"something","Picture":"4w84sdf78d25s0.jpg"}
```

Comment: What is the path /Example/GetData referring to? Is that a single file? A server? What does the server code look like?

Comment: Are you sure your `JASON` is not a string format or what is showing in the `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Switch the `console.log`s around, and get the value of `console.log(data)` first. You will be able to see if the `data` matches your `JSON` response

Comment: console.log() shows like this: {"ProductId":22,"Title":"my wallet","Des":"something","Picture":"4w84sdf78d25s0.jpg"}

Comment: try this => `console.log(typeof data)` and see what shows up. Is it showing as `object `or `string` ?

Comment: You can tell jQuery to expect and parse the response as JSON using the following... `$.post('/Example/GetData', { Id: _Id }, 'json')`

Comment: console.log(typeof data) returns: string

Comment: try this `let dataParsed = JSON.parse(data)` and then `console.log(dataParsed.Title)`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping better to get jQuery to do the parsing, that way it will fail the deferred response if the JSON is invalid

Comment: @Phil Agree! But just trying to help out to get it resolved as much as possible in comments.

Comment: From the duplicate, I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475737/283366)

Comment: Thanks guys! that was the case. I used var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(obj.Title); and works now!

Comment: @Palmal Happy to help as always :)